# How do I know which file is open in Windows from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to know which file is open in Windows from command line. In linux we have command lsof for that purpose. Is there any command in Windows like that?

Comment: Same as [
'lsof' equivalent for windows
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/lsof-equivalent-for-windows).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Are you referring to current running processes? That would be: `tasklist`

If you want to view running processes of the current user:

`tasklist /FI "username eq user"`

Change `user` and put the current username.

Comment: can the downvoter(s) please explain?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but your answer simply does not apply: the question quit clearly states a list of files is wanted, not processes.

Comment: Well I thought it was what he meant (processes). Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Ruel do you have any idea how do i achive that how do i close a file that is runing under certain process for example

Comment: ruby.exe pid: 556 TIGOC\x0138466 744: File (RW-) C:\DOCUME~1\x0138466\LOCALS~1\Temp\CGI.556.1 748: File (RW-) C:\Documents and Settings\x0138466\Local Settings\Temp 74C: File (RW-) C:\DOCUME~1\x0138466\LOCALS~1\Temp\mongrel.556.0 760: File (RW-) C:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\upload\log\development.log 784: File (RW-) C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2982_x-ww_ac3f9c03 7B0: File (RW-) C:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\upload\log\development.log

Comment: here ruby is the process thats running with pid 556 ,from there i have to delete this 744 :File (RW-) C:\DOCUME~1\x0138466\LOCALS~1\Temp\CGI.556.1 748:

Comment: sorry for this inconveniance process

Comment: amit- if a process or dll is using a file, the file can't be deleted. You have to close the process.. or I guess unload the dll..  sysinternals process explorer, and unlocker, are apps relevant to that. Problem is that sometimes explorer.exe locks it. svchost.exe can too. these can be a little hassle to deal with. For explorer.exe, you can open task manager,and a command prompt,end task explorer.exe then delete it from the command prompt. Then file..new task..explorer.exeFor svchost.exe maybe just close it.. but process explorer can show what services are associated with it and you can end it

Comment: Ruel, files are opened and closed for reading or writing.  One doesn't talk about opening or closing processes. One runs processes. processes are running, or not, and there may be other states other than running. Processes and files are different things. A process is an instance of an executable file, in main memory(ram).    You can run many notepad.exe processes. There's only one file there. Anyhow,you gave him a solution that ignores all data files open. And by the way. Tasklist without parameters gives a list of processes.

Answer (score 23):

If you want a command line tool, the [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) utility from SysInternals does this.  For a GUI tool, check out [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: and one more thing i would like to know is it possible to close a file  Running under a specific process using handle ,i don't want to close the process but a file that is opened .

Comment: @AMIT: `handle -c <handle id> -p <process id>`

Comment: ruby.exe pid: 556 TIGOC\x0138466
  744: File  (RW-)   C:\DOCUME~1\x0138466\LOCALS~1\Temp\CGI.556.1
  748: File  (RW-)   C:\Documents and Settings\x0138466\Local Settings\Temp
  74C: File  (RW-)   C:\DOCUME~1\x0138466\LOCALS~1\Temp\mongrel.556.0
  760: File  (RW-)   C:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\upload\log\development.log
  784: File  (RW-)   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2982_x-ww_ac3f9c03
  7B0: File  (RW-)   C:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\upload\log\development.log

Comment: ars ruby.exe is process running with pid 556 ,from there i have to delete file with number 7444 how do i do that without closing ruby.exe with id 556

Comment: handle -p 556 -c 744

Comment: This is the correct answer. The handle utility is the Windows equivalent of lsof.